# MouseUp doesn't get called on Grid.Children.Clear()

Tags: c#, wpf, grid, mouse

I have this code in a class derived from `UserControl` (same behavior when it's derived from Window). The code is a very simple sample (isolates the problem) from a project where I want to move some lines with the mouse only between mouse down and mouse up (I can't have direct references to those lines) and the only way is to remove them and add them again to correct position.

```
protected override void OnMouseLeftButtonDown(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    m_Grid.Children.Clear( );
    m_Grid.Children.Add(new Button());
    base.OnMouseLeftButtonDown(e);
}

protected override void OnMouseLeftButtonUp(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    m_Grid.Children.Clear();
    base.OnMouseLeftButtonUp(e);
}
```

Where `m_Grid` is declared like this:

```
private readonly Grid m_Grid;
```

In this form `OnMouseLeftButtonUp` never gets called. 
If I remove:

```
m_Grid.Children.Clear( );
m_Grid.Children.Add(new Button());
```

`OnMouseLeftButtonUp` gets called.

Do you know why?

Comment: Although you question is a little bit unclear.What makes you say that is not called ? How did you test this behavior ?

Comment: By using a breakpoint in OnMouseLeftButtonUp. Also I could say this by seeing the button after mouse up:P

Comment: I suggest using [Snoop](http://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/) to see which element in visual tree is handling your event.

Comment: I tried your code on a grid width a small width and height and it worked well !

Comment: My guess is that the button you are adding is added somwhere under your mouse cursor, so the up event is handled by the newly added button.
Try hooking the OnPreviewMouseLeftButtonUp. If that one fires, your button is probably handling OnMouseLeftButtonUp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you have set the `Window`'s or `UserControl` mouseUp event so :
At moment you do the MouseUp, the cursor has to be on the `Window` or `UserControl`'s surface not on the `Button` or on the grid, so it can fire the MouseUp event.

To resolve this issue, add:

```
protected override void OnPreviewMouseLeftButtonUp(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            m_Grid.Children.Clear();
            base.OnPreviewMouseLeftButtonUp(e);
        }
```

Comment: Is there a easy way to forward the event for parents? I don't want to derive classes from every shape and forward the event to parent.

Comment: This didn't worked for me in the original project- OnPreviewMouseLeftButtonUp wasn't called. I used CaptureMouse() in OnPreviewMouseLeftButtonDown() and release the capture in OnMouseLeftButtonUp() to make it work